# Using let to change the opacity of a view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native and have it set up so when a TouchableOpacity has been touched the opacity of another TouchableOpacity change and the touched TouchableOpacity has a higher opacity. Looking for how to fix or suggestions for improvement.

```
let opacityEnglish= true ? 1 : 0.5
let opacitySpanish = false ? 1 : 0.5

const languageSetHandler = (language) => {
    if(language == 'English') {
        opacityEnglish = true;
        opacitySpanish = false;
    }
    else if (language== 'Spanish') {
        opacitySpanish = true;
        opacityEnglish = false;
    }
    setLanguage(language);
}

<TouchableOpacity 
    style={styles.OtherStyles, {opacity: opacityEnglish}} onPress={() => languageSetHandler('English')}>
         <Text>English</Text>
         <Text>Has been selected</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It has been suggested not to use a boolean for the let. Any Alternative ways to change the opacity from outside the TouchOpacity?

Comment: Hi David, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opacityEnglish` & `opacitySpanish` are instance variable's. Your `languageSetHandler` function changes instance variable's, but `React` won't reacts when instance variable changes.

I think you have 2 options here.

1. You can directly use `language` for your opacity,

```
const languageSetHandler = (language) => {
    setLanguage(language);
}

<TouchableOpacity 
    style={styles.OtherStyles, {opacity: language === 'English' ? 1 : 0.5}} 
    onPress={() => languageSetHandler('English')}
>
    <Text>English</Text>
    <Text>Has been selected</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You can do same for `Spanish`.

2. You can maintain opacity in state,

```
const [opacityEnglish, setOpacityEnglish] = useState(0.5); //You can set initial opacity to 1 as per your need
const [opacitySpanish, setOpacitySpanish] = useState(0.5);

const languageSetHandler = (language) => {
    if(language == 'English') {
        setOpacityEnglish(1);
        setOpacitySpanish(0.5);
    }
    else if (language== 'Spanish') {
        setOpacityEnglish(0.5);
        setOpacitySpanish(1);
    }
    setLanguage(language);
}
<TouchableOpacity 
    style={styles.OtherStyles, {opacity: opacityEnglish}} 
    onPress={() => languageSetHandler('English')}
>
    <Text>English</Text>
    <Text>Has been selected</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Great answers! However, Option 1 allows more than one language to be selected at once since clicking one won't change the activation of the other, and Option 2 gives me a violation of too many re-renders. I tried styles.EnglishLang.opacity = 1 before and it worked but it only works for an Image and not for text, view, or toucableOpacity.

Comment: Can you provide the codepen for what you have tried.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by *Option 1 allows more than one language to be selected at once*, as we are setting only 1 language at a time `onPress={() => languageSetHandler('English')}`?

Comment: Yes you are right, but in the app, it takes more than one tap for it to register that we switched languages. It is not lagging, just won't render fast enough between switching languages.

Comment: Probably you can handle this using loader. You can show loader till the language gets changed on first tap. If the issue with app itself then you need to find another way.

Comment: The thing is the more I look at it, it is not a speed problem. I tap Spanish and it reads the ? 1, but when I tap English again the ': 0.5' is never read or acknowledge. So now English is 1 and Spanish is 1

Comment: Interesting, can you provide the codepen for this, I will try to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

`let opacityEnglish= true ? 1 : 0.5`

This will always resolve to 1, because `true` is always true.

I think you want something more like:

`let opacity = language === 'english' ? 1 : 0.5`;

Comment: what could be something that works without a boolean?

Comment: The thing is that it takes two taps to render properly and then I have to tap again to deactivate, I want it so if it is English then it is selected, if it is Spanish then English will automatically be disabled and continue like that for all languages.